# STM32 - Cortex M3: STIR register

Tags: stm32, interrupt, cortex-m

I'm trying to write code in order to generate software trigger. Datasheets seem confusing to me and I cannot find any example on NET.
In the "Cortex-M3 devices Generic User Guide" in 4.2.8 I read to write in NVIC->STIR register to generate a software interrupt:
[STIR register][1]

But, if I understood correctly USERSETMPEND must be set to 1 for unprivileged software (I think it's my case).
But If I want to access to SCR I have to be "privileged"
[SCR register][2]

So, how can I enter in privileged mode? Is it really necessary enter in this mode only for interrupt configuration?
What I've done in code is

```
   SCB->CCR |= 0x02; // USERSETMPEND = 1. But I must be "privileged"
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn); // enable interrupt line
   .... some code....
   ... ...
   if(my_software_trigger)
    {

   my_software_trigger = 0;
   NVIC->STIR = EXTI0_IRQn; // triggers interrupt??
  }
```

Is it the correct approach? Anyone has experience in this matter? Any help is really appreciatedd..

P.s. Sorry for my english

Marco.

Comment: how are you not in priveledged mode.  are you looking at the right documentation armv7m not armv7(ar)?    if this is a cortex-m3 then you likely are not using modes and the modes are not what you think.

Comment: and what is your definition of software trigger?  you would normally use svc (aka swi) to cause a software interrupt but that does not go through the nvic, anything nvic related would be in the chip vendors logic/documentation and you would not find in the arm documentation.  The arm documentation does talk about setting the pending interrupt in the nvic, but does that cause an interrupt?  I would have to experiment.

Comment: your primary arm documents are the arm architectural reference manual armv7-m, and the cortex-m3 technical reference manual (current and the one specific for the revision of your core), some of  arms other docs are not that great, so use with a grain of salt...

Comment: Hi old_timer, thanks for all the advices you provided me. You opened my eyes :) . To solve the problem, as you suggested, I used the SVC call using the __asm instruction.

Comment: nice...wasnt quite sure what you were trying to do but suspected that might be it...good luck have fun.